# Reset options dropdown menu 2 when first selected item box 1 is changed mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, drop-down-menu

I used this code to hide a selected option from dropdownmenu 2. But when a user after that changes the first option, i want tot reset the second dropdown list to prevent that the same value is selected twice.

ex.

- List 1 : select A
- List 2 : select B
- List 1 : select B **

  ** How can I reset list 2 at this moment when list 1 is changed? This to prevent that list 1 and list 2 get the same value (B)!

Thanks and kind regards

HMTL:

```
<select name="anfang">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
<select name="secondSelect">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript:

```
var select1 = document.querySelector('select[name="anfang"]'),
secondList= document.querySelectorAll('select[name="secondSelect"]
option');
select1.onchange = function(){
    var selected = this.value;
    for(var i=0;i<secondList.length;i++){
         if(secondList[i].value==selected)
            secondList[i].setAttribute('disabled',true);
         else if(secondList[i].getAttribute('disabled'))
            secondList[i].removeAttribute('disabled');
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the issue you are having with this code? Seems to work for me. https://jsfiddle.net/mbfczbbq/

Comment: Nevermind, I see what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this a few ways. I personally like to set it to a blank value, but you can just unselect the value you are disabling like:

```
     if(secondList[i].value==selected) {
        secondList[i].setAttribute('disabled',true);
        secondList[i].selected = false;
     } else if(secondList[i].getAttribute('disabled')) {
        secondList[i].removeAttribute('disabled');
     }
```

See [example](https://jsfiddle.net/mbfczbbq/1/).

Comment: Glad it is working for you. Please mark as the correct answer then. Thanks.